# How we know that there are UNIQUE form of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, complex-numbers

As the title described, i need to proof this theorem :

let $Z$ be a complex number

there are only **unique** couple of reals  $a$ and $b$ where $Z=a+ib$.

my question is how did you know if there are a complex number that can't be written like $Z=a+ib$

i searched over the web but all of sources let it without proving

[take a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Qfq.png)

**Edit**

i defined a complex number as any function that including the unit $i=\sqrt{-1}$

then $Z= f(i) $

simple example:  $Z= f(i)=\arctan(i)^{i \ln(i)} $

so again how we can  proof that this expression or any other can be written as $f(i)= a+i b $
where *$a$* and **$a$** are reals

Comment: Your question is why every complex number $z\in\Bbb C$ can be written in the form $a+ib$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers?  Let me turn the question around... how do you **define** complex numbers in the first place?  It seems to me that the answer of why we can always write them in this form should become obvious once thats done...

Comment: Please include in your question the definition of the complex numbers that you are working with.

Comment: @JMoravitz It seems to me that the OP is asking how we know that $a+bi=c+di$ implies $a=c,\ b=d,$ but the answer is the same.   How do you define them?

Comment: Your write-up, in addition to not giving a definition of complex numbers, mixes up two different questions.  (1) Can any complex number $a+bi$ be expressed in such form in more than one way? (I.e. are the real and imaginary parts of a complex number "unique")  (2) Is there a complex number that *cannot* be expressed in the form $a+bi$?  Both are reasonable questions (once Readers are given the definition of "complex number" you want to use), but they are different questions with different answers.

Comment: The definition of complex numbers that *I'm* used to is $\Bbb C = \{(a,b)~:~a,b\in\Bbb R\}$ with addition of complex numbers defined as $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and multiplication of complex numbers defined as $(a,b)\times (c,d)=(a\cdot c - b\cdot d, a\cdot d+b\cdot c)$, using normal addition and multiplication of reals.  For convenience sake, we can opt to represent the complex number $(a,b)$ instead as $a+bi$.  The definition of equality of complex numbers in this case would be $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$, to which the uniqueness is immediate, as is the existence.

Comment: Given that your linked image contains the line "$(x,y)=x+yi$", I am fairly certain that this is how your book defines them as well.

Comment: "*I defined a complex number as any function of $i=\sqrt{-1}$*"  This is a terrible definition.  A function requires both a domain and a codomain.  If your codomain is the complex numbers... then you are using the set of complex numbers to define itself yielding a circular definition.  Perhaps you mean to say that you are defining the complex numbers as the [field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) $\Bbb R[\sqrt{-1}]$ instead?

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry, you are right , i didn't mean "function" as his mathematical definition, but just i mean that any structure including the unite $i$

Comment: Any "*structure*" is also ambiguous and equally terrible.  Here's a suggestion.  Completely forget what you thought you learned the definition of the complex numbers to be, and instead use a definition of complex numbers that is actually common, rigorous, unambiguous, and useful such as the definition I provided in my second comment above.

Comment: Afterall, there are many expressions, functions, or "structures" which involve $i$ which result in numbers that are not complex numbers such as the result being [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).  I would consider $5+i(2+i-j+k)$ to be an expression or a "*structure*" as you might call it which involves $i$, but I would very much not consider the result a complex number because it isn't.

Comment: @hardmath Yeah they are both reasonable questions,  i meant the second suggestion; (2) Is there a complex number that cannot be expressed in the form a+bi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "i defined a complex number as any function that including the unit $i=\sqrt{-1}$
>
> then $Z=f(i)$
>
> simple example: $Z=f(i)=\arctan(i)^{iln(i)}$
>
> so again how we can proof that this expression or any other can be written as $f(i)=a+ib$
> where $a$ and $b$ are reals"

We can't using your "definition" because it is incorrect.

According to your definition, $i\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $i\oplus \heartsuit$, $5+i-j+2k$, $\{i,\{2\},\emptyset\}$, and many other things should count as "complex numbers" but many of those most certainly can *not* be written in the form $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ both real numbers.  Under more standard definitions, none of those I just listed are considered complex numbers but are instead considered something else entirely.

---

One of the correct and common ways to define the complex numbers would be as

$$\Bbb C=\{(a,b)~:~a,b\in\Bbb R\}$$ with the operations of addition and multiplication defined as:

$$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$$

$$(a,b)\times (c,d)=(a\cdot c-b\cdot d,b\cdot c+a\cdot d)$$

where the addition and multiplication of real numbers is otherwise the usual addition and multiplication we are used to.

Further, equality of complex numbers is defined as $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$, where equality of real numbers is defined as normal.

For convenience sake, we may choose to represent a complex number $(a,b)$ in the form $a+bi$, potentially omitting either the $a$ or the $bi$ if exactly one of them is zero.

From this definition, letting $z\in\Bbb C$, the existence of a real $a,b$ such that $z=a+bi$ is immediate since the only elements in $\Bbb C$ are by definition those which can be written in that form.  Further, that such a representation is unique is again immediate from the definition, because that is how equality was *defined* in the first place.

Comment: Additionally, the definition used by the asker also throws into question the idea of uniqueness. What is it that makes $i^2$ and $i^6$ "the same"? They are different functions of $i$.

Comment: Mr @JMoravitz thank you for answer. i know all of what you have said, and that what i am finding in other references, but sorry this is not the answer of what i asked for, still without answer.
 i'll try to reform my question: 
according to your definition of a complex number;  is it any expression of other complexe number is also necessary a complex number ?

Comment: @ElMouden if your question here is "Is an expression such as $\arctan(i)^{i\ln(i)}$ a complex number?", the answer is yes **assuming** that all functions appearing within the expression are functions with both domain and codomain as the complex numbers (*as are the case with appropriate definitions of most if not all elementary functions such as exponentiation, trigonometric formulae, complex logarithms, etc...*) as the expression could then be expressed by the output of composition of complex functions, and as such expressed by the output of *a* complex function, thereby being a complex num

Comment: For more information as to why that would be, you will need to look at the definitions of **each individual function**., for example the complex sine function which is defined as the function $\sin(z) = z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+\dots \pm \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+\dots$, noting that the power series on the right converges and is well defined for all complex numbers $z$ and results in a complex number.  Similar such definitions can be found for other elementary functions.

Comment: Some functions however do not result in complex numbers, such as those I listed above.  For example a function which takes complex numbers as inputs and outputs a matrix, or one that takes complex numbers as inputs and outputs a quaternion, etc...

Comment: it's clear, i understand now, you said that the result depending to the function used, if hir output is not a complex num, then the result of course can't be written as $a+ib$, then we can not call the result " a complex number " , if that what you mean i understand and thank you very much

Comment: @JMoravitz I finally understand, I really appreciate your efforts, Thank you sir